# After creating an array and pushing objects to it, objects are [Object] and not the actual data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, data-manipulation

In node, I am trying to mutate an array of objects from S3 (super annoying response to parse) into something more front end useable. 
The initial object format is:

```
[
  {
    Key: 'some/folder/structure/file.jpg',
    LastModified: 2020-05-14T02:16:59.000Z,
    ETag: '"SomeETag"',
    Size: 83630,
    StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
  }
]
```

I am trying to mutate this into an array like:

```
name: "some"
files: [
  {

    key: 'some/folder/structure/file.jpg',
    name: 'file.jpg',
    folder: 'folder',
    subfolder: 'structure'

  }
]
```

key is the key I need to retrieve the object from s3.
name is the name of file for front end display.
folder ends up being the top level folder I want to display the file in.
Subfolder is anything between folder and the file name.

This processing will make an object for each actual top level folder from s3 ('some' in the example). this object will have a name, and a list of file objects like the one above.

Here is my function to do such:

```
function processResponse(res) {
  var result = [];
  res.forEach(item =>{
    if(item.Key.slice(-1) === '/') return;
    const split = item.Key.split('/');
    var obj = {
      key: item.Key,
      name: split[split.length-1],
      folder: split[1],
      subfolder: split.length <= 3 ? '' : split.join([2,split.length-2])
    }
    var index = result.findIndex(x => x.name === split[1])
    if(index === -1) {
      result = [...result, {
        name: split[1],
        files: []
      }]
      index = result.length-1
    }
    result[index].files = [...result[index].files, obj];
  });
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

The issue I am seeing is with the files array for any individual folder. When I console log the resulting array, instead of displaying the data for each file, the return looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Forms',
    files: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
]
```

Besides the data being missing, it also seems to break the return to front end. How can I push the actual data into each file array so it can be console.log-ed and returned correctly?

Bonus: I think the way I make the subfolder string is wrong. Basically I want anything from split[2] to the last folder before the file or '' if split only has a length of 3.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's just the way the console shows deeply nested objects.

Comment: Use `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: Even better, use a debugger

Comment: BTW, `result[index].files = [...result[index].files, obj]` can be written more simply as `result[index].files.push(obj)`

Comment: use |`console.log( JSON.stringify(result,0,2) )`

Comment: @Barmar, you're right about the simplification. This was just an attempt to try and fix the apparent non-issue. any idea why it returns null to the front end when I query the node url? I get a 200 response of document, but it doesn't log it to the screen like if i just return the response.

Comment: I don't know much about using node.js for back-end, so I'm not sure how any of this relates to what gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this works fine and my issue was not understanding how the console obscures deep data structured. To view the full data, all I needed to do was:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result,0,2))
```